# Why this css ticker use only first four posts

Tags: html, css, ticker

Hey I want add News Ticker to my rails app. I found this CSS ticker: http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-news-ticker

I don't know why it display only four first posts.
Can you help me change this code to display all posts from my table, to retrieve data I'm using .each loop so I think this is not the main problem.

Comment: You cannot use that for your app, because they are using css animation which is applied only for 4 elements...

Comment: 0%   {margin-top: 0;}
 25%  {margin-top: -26px;}
 50%  {margin-top: -52px;}
 75%  {margin-top: -78px;}
 100% {margin-top: 0;} if your app have something n elements, you cannot animate with % positions...need to find some other ways to do it..

Comment: Thank @yjs for this explanation. Now I understand how it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a dynamic one with the example you gave, I calculate through JS the amount of li and then I calculate what's the % of the keyframe by dividing 100 for the number of `li's` inside the `ul`. You can check the example here:

https://jsfiddle.net/erv1b8nh/2/

The js is the following:

```
var style = document.documentElement.appendChild(document.createElement("style")),
  rule1 = " ticker { 0%   { margin-top:0; }";
  rule2 = " 100% { margin-top:0; } }";

  var n = $('#news li').length;
  var rule3 = "";
  var help = 1;
  var nSpin = (100/n).toFixed(2);
  while(n > 1)
  {
    rule3 = rule3 + " " + nSpin*help + "% { margin-top:" + help*-27 + "px; }";
    help = help + 1;
    n = n - 1;

  }

  rule = rule1 + rule3 + rule2;

if (CSSRule.KEYFRAMES_RULE) { // W3C
  style.sheet.insertRule("@keyframes" + rule, 0);
} else if (CSSRule.WEBKIT_KEYFRAMES_RULE) { // WebKit
  style.sheet.insertRule("@-webkit-keyframes" + rule, 0);
}
```

Of course then based on the amount of elements you should adjust the animation time.
Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Thanks Signo you're right!

Comment: @schadock No problem! :)